# Is Tyrus nessary to implement Java WebSocket authentication?

Tags: tyrus

Although there's very similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353710/java-websocket-wss-authentication), it is unanswered.

My JavaFX app with WebSocket will

1. send user id、password to server
2. keep the session to let user do something like personal data management.

Learning from

[Oracle WebSocket](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/BinaryWebSocket/binaryWebSocket.html)、
[Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.9/user-guide.html) 8.14 Client HTTP Authentication

I have:

```java
@ClientEndPoint
public class loginEndPoint {
    final ClientEndpointConfig cec = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create().build();

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        AuthConfig authConfig = AuthConfig.Builder.create().disableBasicAuth().build();
        Credentials credentials = new Credentials("ws_user", "password");
        client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.AUTH_CONFIG, authConfig);
        client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.CREDENTIALS, credentials);

        client.connectToServer(new Endpoint() {

            @Override
            public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
                try {
                    session.addMessageHandler((MessageHandler.Whole<String>) (String message) -> {
                        System.out.println("Received message: "+message);
                        messageLatch.countDown();
                    });
                    //let user do some data management
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Connect Fail.");
                }
            }
        }, cec, new URI("ws://localhost/myApp/login"));
    }
}
```

Is these code right to do the authentication? And where could I do the server side authentication on @ServerEndPoint?

```java
@ServerEndpoint
public class loginServerEndPoint {
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not necessary to use Tyrus as a server implementation.
On the server-side you should secure WebSocket in exactly the same way as you secure servlet or jsp in your servlet container, which can be slightly different from container to container (mapping users to roles).
Look at [authentication example](https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/tree/master/samples/echo-basic-auth/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF) 
Note that this example shows up how to make authenticated WebSocket request handshake with BASIC auth scheme, but your client code disables it explicitly, so probably you want to use DIGEST scheme.

Comment: I'm so sorry.  I really don't understand.  Why the example refers to "web.xml"?  Do you mean all I need to do on server side is setting the web.xml?  I thought the meaning of authentication is: server side will examine the id&password, then save something on session variable.  Do I misunderstand the whole thing?

Comment: Excuse me, do you mean web.xml defines where the server side authentication program is?  Could you tell me which tag do the job? Does it the same in tomcat too?  How do you figure this out, because I don't see any clue on [Tyrus guide](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.9/user-guide.html).  Thanks for your answer.